# как проитерировать древовидную таблицу и присвоить ссылочное поле

Tags: lsfusion

вот в таком древовидном классе

```
CLASS Razdel 'Разделы';
prn = DATA INTEGER (Razdel);
cd = DATA INTEGER (Razdel);
tit = DATA ISTRING[255] (Razdel);
parent = DATA Razdel(Razdel);
```

в полях **prn** находятся значения соответсвующие полям **cd** parent-записей, поля **parent** пока пустые

подскажите пожалуйста как проитерировать теперь эту таблицу чтобы в поле **parent** возникли соответствующие иерархии значения, т.е. что-то подобное по смыслу:

```
FOR Razdel r DO {
    parent(r) <- Razdel WHERE cd(Razdel) = prn(r);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR cd(Razdel parent) == prn(Razdel item) DO {
  parent(item) <- parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, для начала, построить свойство, которое будет по коду *cd* возвращать объект класса Razdel :

```
razdel (INTEGER cd) = GROUP MAX Razdel r BY cd(r);
```

Или вместо GROUP MAX использовать GROUP AGGR (тоже самое, но с ограничением на уникальность)

```
razdel (INTEGER cd) = GROUP AGGR Razdel r BY cd(r);
```

А потом уже, используя это свойство проставить parent :

```
parent (Razdel r) <- razdel(prn(r));
```